# C++ get a random value that hasn't been used yet in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

I'm making a tic tac toe game and I'm making the player's opponent now. As you know a tic tac toe match has 9 fields, so I've made a vector that contains all the fields that are already used by other X's and O's.

```
std::vector<int> UsedPositions;
```

So before I tried getting a random value with srand(time()) and iterate through the vector to check if that position was already being used. It actually worked but it took, as you can imagine, a lot of calculations (thus time) for my poor CPU because if the vector had about 8 elements it would mean it would have to iterate 8 times (that is IF the random number is distinct, else it would have to go through it another 8 times).

TL;DR - How do I get a distinct random value that is < 10 && > 0 from a vector?

Code thats slow for me:

```
int FindUniqueAnswer()
{
    int answer;
    bool AnswerFound = false;

    while(!AnswerFound)
    {
        bool DoesntEqual = true;
        srand(time(0));
        int random = rand()%10;
        if(random == 0)
        {
            random++;
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<UsedPositions.size();i++)
        {
            if(random == UsedPositions.at(i))
            {
                DoesntEqual = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(DoesntEqual)
        {
            answer = random;
            AnswerFound = true;
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: A linear scan of a 9-element array would take well under a microsecond. Are you genuinely worried about performance, or is this more of a theoretical concern?

Comment: theoretical, yes. But the lag was certainly noticeable on my laptop :)

Comment: You noticed a sub-microsecond lag? Something else is going on.

Comment: I'm afraid so. I'm fairly new to programming so I wasn't sure but I'll try debugging it. Is the way I explained the way you would do it?

Comment: No, but it's the way I would advise a noob to do it. You should add the relevant code to your question for review. There is no way, come hell or high water, a linear scan of a 9-element array with a simple boolean test at each element could cause a noticeable lag. Even if the array had a million elements, it still should happen in the blink of an eye.

Comment: I'm pretty sure ur right mate I'll try and reconstruct my previous code and check out what's causing it

Comment: Anyone found the answer yet? :\

Comment: @user1534664 upload the entire source so I can compile it.

Comment: http://www.2shared.com/file/kAsx0OJm/SDL.html
Thanks ALOT for ur effort man im going nuts lol

Comment: Post it on http://www.liveworkspace.org Judging by the file name this is an SDL project?

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/386f486f499426879bf9c4c082f1b76f

Comment: @user1534664 SDL might be why it's so slow. It is (imo) a very annoying library to use.

Comment: I doubt thats the problem, because before I just used a counter that went up from 1 to 9 and checked if it was in the vector already and that didnt lag a single bit :) and lol it was recommened to me, it was supposed to give me some basics on gaming development. What library do you recommend?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16454/discussion-between-rapptz-and-user1534664)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
...
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::random_device rd
mt19937 g(rd());
shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
```

Copied from cppreference.com

Comment: +1 for identifying this as a shuffle instead of saying how fast a linear scan of a vector is. =)